# How can a write a script that stop when I write =?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script: I type in numbers, and when I type =, then it will sum up all the previous numbers. I've tried this, but it is not working:

```
a= int(input())
while a != '=':
  szum += a
  if a == '=':
    break
    print(szum)
```

I wish to solve this with while/if/else function, if that is possible.

Comment: You never fetch new input or change `a` so it'll never equal `=`. Also, you should *always* explain what "not working" means.

Comment: Add ```input``` inside the ```while``` block.

Answer (score 4):

Raymond Hettinger's [Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go&t=12m28s) has an elegant solution to this problem; the two-argument form of [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```py
# NOTE: Missing parens is intentional! iter's two-argument form takes
# a callable that can be invoked with no args (`input` -> `input()`),
# and the sentinel value to stop at.
#
# It yields consecutive return values from `input()` until '=' is found.

total = 0
for i in iter(input, '='):
    total += int(i)
print(total)
```

Or the even more beautiful:

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in iter(input, '='))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
a = input()
zsum = 0
while a!='=':
    zsum += int(a)
    a=input()
print(zsum)
```

Take into account that you're not checking for wrong inputs, so writing a letter different that '=' will result into an exception. To solve this, you can manage those exceptions with a `try-except` block like this:

```
a = input()
zsum = 0
while a!='=':
    try:
        zsum += int(a)
    except:
        print('input not valid')
    finally:
        a=input()
print(zsum)
```

EDIT: As pointed by Brian Rodriguez at the comments. This solution might lead to poor information for the error. You could solve this and keep the program running by showing the exception error like this:

```
a = input()
zsum = 0
while a!='=':
    try:
        zsum += int(a)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        a=input()
print(zsum)
```

Comment: `int` raises a very informative error when the input is invalid, but you're replacing it with a less informative one. Would be better to let `int` do its job; `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'` vs your `input not valid`.

Comment: Yes, but not controlling the exception will lead to an execution stop, and the final user (who doesn't have to know what valueError means) will be confused. By controlling it, you let the user know that their input is wrong but they can try with some other one

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using best of both worlds, print the exception's message instead and allow execution to continue.

Comment: Seems logic to me, I'll add it to the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:)

```
a = 0
sum = 0
while 1==1:
    a = input()
    if a == '=':
        print(sum)
        break
    sum += int(a)
```